# How will I improve mysql query that retrieves 11.2m data?

Tags: mysql

```
select tblfarmerdetails.ncode,
tblfarmerdetails.region,tblfarmerdetails.province, tblfarmerdetails.municipality,
concat(tblfarmerdetails.farmerfname, ' ', tblfarmerdetails.farmerlname) as nameoffarmer,
 concat(tblfarmerdetails.spousefname, ' ',tblfarmerdetails.spouselname) as nameofspouse, tblstatus.statusoffarmer from tblfarmerdetails
 INNER Join
 tblstatus on tblstatus.ncode = tblfarmerdetails.ncode where tblstatus.ncode = tblfarmerdetails.ncode order by tblfarmerdetails.region
```

It takes too long to retrieve 11.2m data. How will I improve this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, format the query so it is readable, or at least decipherable, by a human.

```
  SELECT f.ncode
       , f.region
       , f.province
       , f.municipality
       , CONCAT(f.farmerfname,' ',f.farmerlname) AS nameoffarmer
       , CONCAT(f.spousefname,' ',f.spouselname) AS nameofspouse
       , s.statusoffarmer
    FROM tblfarmerdetails
    JOIN tblstatus s
      ON s.ncode = f.ncode
   ORDER BY f.region
```

It's likely that a lot of time is spent to do a "Using filesort" operation, to sort all the rows in the order specified in the `ORDER BY` clause. For sure a sort operation is going to occur if there's not an index with a leading column of `region`.

Having a suitable index available, for examaple

```
... ON tblfarmerdetails (region, ... )
```

Means that MySQL may be able to return the rows "in order", using the index,  without having to do a sort operation.

If MySQL has a "covering index" available, i.e. an index that contains *all* of the columns of the table reference in the query, MySQL can make use of that index to satisfy the query without needing to visit pages in the underlying table.

But given the number of columns, and the potential that some of these columns may be goodly sized VARCHAR, this may not be possible or workable:

```
... ON tblfarmerdetails (region, ncode, province, municipality, farmerfname, farmerlname,  spousefname, spouselname)
```

(MySQL does have some limitations on indexex. The goal of the "covering index" is to avoid lookups to pages in the table.)

And make sure that MySQL knows that `ncode` is UNIQUE in `tblstatus`. Either that's the PRIMARY KEY or there's a UNIQUE index.

We suspect `tblstatus` table contains a small number of rows, so the join operation is probably not that expensive. But an appropriate covering index, with ncode as the leading column, wouldn't hurt:

```
 ... ON tblstatus (ncode, statusoffarmer)
```

If MySQL has to performa a "Using filesort" operation to get the rows ordered (to satisfy the `ORDER BY` clause), on a large set, that operation can spill to disk, and that can add (sometimes significantly) to the elapsed time.

The resultset produced by the query has to be transferred to the client. And that can also take some clock time.

And the client has to do something with the rows that are returned.

Are you sure you really need to return 11.2M rows? Or, are you only needing the first couple of thousand rows?

Consider adding a `LIMIT` clause to the query.

And how long are those `lname` and `fname` columns? Do you need MySQL to do the concatenation for you, or could that be done on the client as the rows are proceesed.

It's possible that MySQL is having to do a "Using temporary" to hold the rows with the concatenated results. And MySQL is likely allocating enough space for that return column to hold the maximum possible length from lname + maximum posible length from fname. And if that's a multibyte character characterset, that will double or triple the storage over a single byte characterset.

---

To really see what's going on, you'd need to take a look at the query execution plan. You get that by preceding your SELECT statement with the keyword EXPLAIN

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

The output from that will show the operations that MySQL is going to do, what indexes it's going to use. And armed with knowledge about the operations the MySQL optimizer can perform, we can use that to make some pretty good guesses as to how to get the biggest gains.

Comment: Ok spencer I got it. Thanks for the words of advise. I think I have the idea now. Thank you so much for the explanation. I apologize for the unreadable query.

Comment: The MySQL tokenizer doesn't care about the formatting of the query... that's purely for human convenience. especially with more complicated queries. Follow the conventions. patterns and standards in your shop, at least until you can demonstrate to your shop the benefits and advantages of a different patterns and conventions.

Comment: Understanding the MySQL optimizer... what operations it can perform, and what influences MySQL to choose which operations to use, and most importantly what prevents MySQL from using particular operations, is the key to SQL performance. And for queries where suitable indexes aren't available, the performance improvement we see from adding an appropriate index can appear almost magical. But I caution against falling into the trap of the knee-jerk "add an index" as a silver bullet panacea. The real key to performance is understanding the optimizer.

Comment: Ok spencer. Thanks again for the advise and clear explanation.